# How to control Textblock properties through TabControl template

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, tabcontrol

I have setup a `TabControl` with custom grid to hold a picture and a `Textblock` object as the design for the headers (`TabItem`). I am currently controlling the background colors of the headers with a template and I cannot figure out how to also control the `Foreground` color of the embedded `TextBlock` using the same template.

I'm a novice Visual Studio C# guy, but my understanding of these Templates is that I can use them to set child properties as well (kind of similar to CSS child selectors)? Or am I completely off?

Here's my "design" -- you'll notice the three tabs on top with custom styling:
[image: Design with three tabs on top]

My current template for the `TabItem`

```
<Setter Property="Template">

    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Grid x:Name="Root">
                <Border x:Name="Border" Margin="0,0,-4,0">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  ContentSource="Header"
                  Margin="12,2,12,2"
                  RecognizesAccessKey="True" />

                </Border>

            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <!-- Selected color -->
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <!-- <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="ContentSite" Value="White"/>-->
                    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FFEF690D" />
                </Trigger>

                <!-- Not Selected color -->
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FFEE8740" />
                </Trigger>

                <!-- Tab mouseovers-->
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FFEFA470" />
                </MultiTrigger>

            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

My current xaml setup for the `TabControl` (less the third `TabItem` for brevity)

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="311" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="717" Background="#FFF9F9F9" Style="{DynamicResource MainMenuTabs}">
  <TabItem Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}">
        <!-- TAB 1 -->
        <TabItem.Header>
              <Grid x:Name="Main" Margin="0" Height="52" Width="166">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="52"/>
                          <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Margin="0,5,0,3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" Grid.Column="1" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"><Run Text="Main"/></TextBlock>
                    <Image x:Name="icons_server_32_png" Margin="10,0,10,10" Source="icons/server-32.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
              </Grid>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem>
        <!-- TAB 2 -->
        <TabItem.Header>
              <Grid x:Name="Backups" Margin="0" Height="52" Width="216">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="52"/>
                          <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Margin="0,5,0,3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" Grid.Column="1" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="Backups"/>
                    <Image x:Name="icons_server_32_png1" Margin="10,0,10,10" Source="icons/magnifier-tool.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
              </Grid>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to accomplish the same sort of task, there is a way to reference parent resources and "query" them for information.

Instead of putting triggers on the `TabItem` to change the color of the font, I put triggers on the `TextBlock` that referenced the `TabItem`'s state.

You'd end up using a `DataTrigger` and bind it using a `RelativeSource` setting. In my case I bound it to the `TabItem` with `{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}`

Here's the XAML style I applied to my `TextBlock` controls:

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderTextStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
    <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HeaderTextColor_NotSelected}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HeaderTextColor}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using LinqToVisualTree ...

[http://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/03/04/linq-to-visual-tree.html](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/)

You can find all the "textBlock" controls within the TabControl as follows:

```
tabControl.Descendants<TextBlock>().Where(d => d.Name=="textBlock");
```

Then you will have control to TextBlock properties

Comment: For some reason the website you suggested is redirecting users who are trying to directly access the post -- word to the wise, search for "LINQ TO VISUAL TREE" on the main page to see the article until it's fixed.

Comment: ah okey, thanks for the hint . hope the proposed solution could help